# @SuppressWarnings("unused") gives warning: Redundant suppression after Android Studio update

Tags: android, static-analysis, android-studio-4.1

I have a private methods in some low level classes that are not currently in use, but I don't want the "Method x is never used" warning potentially obscuring other more important warnings. I added a standard warning suppression for that method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

Up until recently that was working fine, no warning for that method. After upgrading to AS 4.1.1, however, these have started to get a "Redundant suppression" warning. If I remove the suppression the original unused warning comes back.

I'm using Android Studio 4.1.1 (Nov. 4)

Comment: This problem remains with AS Android Studio 4.1.2 
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7042882, built on December 19, 2020

Comment: This problem seems fixed with Android Studio 4.2
Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7322048, built on April 29, 2021

Answer (score 11):

Amusingly, I'm able to work around this by suppressing the suppression warning like so:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({"unused", "RedundantSuppression"})
```

Comment: I'm downvoting that to punish Android Studio, not you. This bug creates an infinite loop of suppression, suppressing the suppression, etc...

Comment: @Philip, that's not how the voting works. I think you're supposed to downvote only if there's a problem with the answer, not whether or not you like what the answer is about, no?

Comment: This really is amusing, thanks for the solution, and I'm pretty sure this should be reported as a bug against either AS or the SDK.

Comment: There is hope: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-249790, indicating it's fixed in IntelliJ IDEA 20.2.3 while current Android Studio (4.1.3) is based on v. 20.1. Nice workaround. :)

Comment: This problem seems fixed with Android Studio 4.2 Build #AI-202.7660.26.42.7322048, built on April 29, 2021

Comment: Nice workaround. Bug still present in 2023 (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1).